# import lxml fails after installing lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I am trying to use lxml library. I am using Pycharm with python 3.6.1 on Windows 7. I have installed lxml-3.8.0-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl using "pip install lxml-3.8.0-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl" lxml shows up in external libraries > site-packages folder, but the interpreter cannot resolve it. Any suggestions?

```
import lxml from etree
```

Comment: That's not how you import - use `from lxml import etree`

Comment: Thanks! That's an embarrassing mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your import statement is not correct. You are importing lxml from etree, where you want to be importing etree from lxml. Do `from lxml import etree`

Comment: Thanks! That's an embarrassing mistake.

Comment: It's ok, at least it was an easy fix!